# How to identify if points are on the left or right side of a circle

Tags: circles

Suppose I have a series of points that are on a 2D plane, and I know they can be fitted to some part of the circumference of a circle.

How can I determine that the points lie on the left or right side of the circle, if they circle were to be split into two semicircles?

Answer (score 3):

If the cosine of the angle is negative, the point is on the left side.If the cosine of the angle is positive, the point is on the right side.